# Error pymysql.err.OperationalError en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola equipo de desarrollo en python, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar  con el siguiente inconveniente en una aplicación muy simple en Python, las primeras líneas de código hacen referencia para  importar objetos , estoy trabajando con flask, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

Import flask could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Aquí nos dicen como arreglar ese error en flask:
How to fix Import could not be resolved from source Pylance - YouTube

Solicitud de ayuda 18 Nov 2022:

Error pymysql.err.OperationalError al ejecutar Python en interacción con Mysql-Phpmyadmin

Cordal saludo, estoy creando un aplicativo por el cual me he guiado, mediante el siguiente tutorial en youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUED5uFmyQI&t=6460s):

Vale mencjonar que la aplicación la tengo conectada con una base de datos que tengo en la web, en un hosting de esos gratuitos, al principiuo me mostraba el siguiente error:

Import flask could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Lo arregle importando el correspondiente controlador mediante la siguiente instrucción:

Python:Select Interpreter

Tal como dicen aquí: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ud9Y2uB4PY&t=22s

Pero al ejecutar el código mediante la instrucción ern la consola

(PruebaPyton) PS C:\PruebaPyton> python app.py me crea el servidor:

http://127.0.0.1:5000

pero al momento de ingresar con dicha URL al explorador por ejemplo Chrome, me muestra lo siguiente:

pymysql.err.OperationalError
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Host' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")

y buscando en Google no veo nada que solucione este inconveniente que incluso tiene que ver con librerías instaladas en el Python :

el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template,request,redirect,url_for,flash  #request es para envio de información, (solicitud de información)
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask import send_from_directory
from datetime import datetime      #almacenamiento de la foto de acuerdo al tiempo
import os

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key=""
mysql= MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']='Host'  #o ftpupload.net
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER']='Usuario'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']='Password'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']='Database'
mysql.init_app(app)

CARPETA=os.path.join('uploads')  # uploads es una carpeta
app.config['CARPETA']=CARPETA

@app.route('/uploads/<nombreFoto>')
def uploads(nombreFoto):
  return send_from_directory(app.config['CARPETA'],nombreFoto)

@app.route('/')   # aqui se escribe el host en el navegador (127.0.0.1:5000)
def index():
    sql="select * from 'tabla_de_base_de_datos';"
    conn=mysql.connect()
    cursor=conn.cursor() #Almacenamos todo lo que se va a ejecutar
    cursor.execute(sql)
    
    olimpicos=cursor.fetchall()
    print(olimpicos)

    conn.commit()
    return redirect('/')
    return render_template('olimpicos/index.html',olimpicos=olimpicos)

#def destroy(IdPais):
   #pass
@app.route('/destroy/<int:IdPais>')
def destroy(IdPais):
 conn=mysql.connect()
 cursor=conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT Bandera FROM tabla_de_base_de_datos WHERE IdPais=%s",IdPais)
 fila=cursor.fetchall()
 os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['CARPETA'],fila[0][5])) #tentativamente en 5, ya que en 5 esta la Bandera
     
 
 cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tabla_de_base_de_datos WHERE IdPais=%s",(IdPais))
 conn.commit()
 return redirect('/')

@app.route('/edit/<int:IdPais>')
def edit(IdPais):
  conn=mysql.connect()
  cursor=conn.cursor()
  cursor.execute("select * from tabla_de_base_de_datos WHERE IdPais=%s",(IdPais))
  empleados=cursor.fetchall()
  conn.commit()
  print(empleados)
  return render_template('empleados/edit.html',empleados=empleados) 
  
@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():

    _Pais=request.form['txtPais']
    _Oro=request.form['txtOro']
    _Plata=request.form['txtPlata']
    _Bronce=request.form['txtBronce']
    _Bandera=request.files['txtBandera']
    idPais=request.form['txtIdPais']
    sql="UPDATE tabla_de_base_de_datos SET Pais=%s,Oro=%s,Plata=%s,Bronce=%s WHERE idPais=%s;"  # ,Bandera=%s
    datos=(_Pais,_Oro,_Plata,_Bronce,idPais) # ,nuevoNombreFoto
    
    conn=mysql.connect()
    cursor=conn.cursor()#Almacenamos todo lo que se va a ejecutar
    
    now= datetime.now()
    tiempo=now.strftime("%Y%H%M%S") 

    #if _foto.filename!='':              _Bandera
    if _Bandera.filename!='':
     #nuevoNombreFoto=tiempo+_foto.filename
     nuevoNombreFoto=tiempo+_Bandera.filename
    #_foto.save("uploads/"+nuevoNombreFoto)
    _Bandera.save("uploads/"+nuevoNombreFoto)
    cursor.execute("SELECT Bandera FROM tabla_de_base_de_datos WHERE idPais=%s", idPais)
    fila=cursor.fetchall()

    os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['CARPETA'],fila[0][5])) #tentativamente en 5, ya que en 5 esta la Bandera
    cursor.execute("UPDATE olimpicos SET Bandera=%s WHERE idPais=%s",(nuevoNombreFoto,idPais))
     #cursor.execute(sql,datos)
    conn.commit(os)
    # quede en 1:10:00 de

    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/create')
def create():
    
    return render_template('empleados/create.html')

@app.route('/store', methods=['POST']) #route_name lo cambiamos por store
def storage():
  _Pais=request.form['txtPais']
  _Oro=request.form['txtOro']
  _Plata=request.form['txtPlata']
  _Bronce=request.form['txtBronce']
  _Bandera=request.files['txtBandera']
   
  if _Pais== ''or _Oro==''or _Plata==''or _Bronce==''or _Bandera=='':
    flash('Recuerda rellenar los datos de los campos')
    return redirect(url_for('create'))
  now=datetime.now()
  tiempo=now.strftime("%Y%H%M%S")

  if _Bandera.filename!='':   #Hay fotografia si no es vacio
    nuevoNombreFoto=tiempo +_Bandera.filename
    _Bandera.save("uploads/"+nuevoNombreFoto)
    sql="INSERT INTO 'olimpicos'('IdPais','Pais','Oro','Plata','Bronce','Bandera') VALUES (NULL,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
    
    
    datos=(_Pais,_Oro,_Plata,_Bronce,nuevoNombreFoto)
    
    conn=mysql.connect()
    cursor=conn.cursor()#Almacenamos todo lo que se va a ejecutar
    cursor.execute(sql,datos)
    conn.commit()
    return redirect('/')

if __name__== '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Sería mejor que resumieras la situación en pocas palabras. Seguramente se podrá explicar sin tener que ver los videos.

Comment: En todo caso, el error `getaddrinfo failed` te dice que hay un problema de ambiente: no tienes configurado un DNS, o tienes mal el nombre de host o algo del estilo. Deberías probar la conexión entre las máquinas y servicios.

Comment: Candid Moe muchas gracias por la ayuda, parece ser que debe de ser el nombre del DNS, por que tengo una aplicacion en Php que se conecta a la misma base de datos pero con otra tabla y todo funciona correctamente!, además desafortunadamente cuando soy breve para explicar la situación otros usuarios se molestan por que dicen que no profundizo ni muestro el código, por eso decidí explicar a profundidad los temas cuando se me presenta un inconveniente .